# How to generate constraint on right shift bitwise operator in Circom

Tags: implementation, circuit

How to generate constraint on right shift bitwise operator in the [circom circuit language](https://github.com/iden3/circom)?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
pragma circom 2.0.0;

template MAIN() {

    signal input v;
    signal output type;

    type <== v >> 5;
}

component main = MAIN();
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error[T3001]: Non quadratic constraints are not allowed!
   ┌─ "/Users/ilia/compiling/main-circom/main.circom":68:5
   │
68 │     type <== v >> 5;
   │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ found here
   │
   = call trace:
     ->MAIN
```

I think this has to do with the fact that `v >> 5` expression can not be re-expressed as a quadratic expression by [the circom compiler](https://docs.circom.io/circom-language/constraint-generation/).

I struggle to rewrite the expression to be quadratic. It might involve writing assignment and constraint as two separate operations, but I'm not sure what a proper validating constraint would be for a right shift.

In terms of test cases, I expect `type` to be $5$ when `v` is $168$ for example.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic on Crypto SE.

Comment: Right shift by n bits is the same as division by 2^n, so you can use that to constrain (multiply the other side by 2^n and use a mask to clear the lower bits). You can just use assignment with `<--`

Comment: I was directed to this stackexchange when i asked a question about Circom on StackOverflow... 
I tried:
`type <-- v >> 5; type * 32 === v & 0xE0;`
but now I get "Non quadratic constraints are not allowed" on the `type * 32 === v & 0xE0` line

Comment: How can I generate constraint for a & bitwise operator? Had a look into circomlib but haven't found anything that quite fits the bill, only see `& 1` but that's not generic enough I don't think.

Comment: I've tried this to generate a constraint on & operator: `signal check; check <-- v & 0xE0; check & 0x1F === 0;` but it's failing with "No quadratic constraints are not allowed!" again

Comment: Who did direct this question to here? There are already SageMath questions and answers there yet this was off-topic?

Comment: I was directed to this stackexchange here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70891895/how-to-pass-function-argument-by-reference-in-circom#comment125326319_70891895 with the reasoning that "crypto.stackexchange.com might be more appropriate for ZKP-related questions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using the LessThan comparator from [circomlib](https://github.com/iden3/circomlib/blob/master/circuits/comparators.circom):

````
//... import comparators from circomlib ...

template MAIN() {

    signal input v;
    signal output type;
    signal check_v;
    component lessThan = LessThan(8);

    type <-- v >> 5;
    check_v <== type*32;
    // use circomlib LessThan to check that (v - check_v) < 32
    lessThan.in[0] <== v - check_v;
    lessThan.in[1] <== 32;    
    lessThan.out === 1;
}

component main = MAIN();
```
````

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thank you! `component lessThan = LessThan(8); // full 8 bits
    lessThan.in[0] <== v - check_v;
    lessThan.in[1] <== 32;
    lessThan.out === 1;`

Comment: Sweet! Updated my answer with the final code then. We should clean up these comments.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This doesn't sufficiently verify the shift operation. See @meshcollider's answer instead.

Ok, i'm not fully sure if this is right, but this is what I came up with.

```
pragma circom 2.0.0;

template MAIN() {

    signal input v;
    signal output type;

    // assign `type` signal
    // shift 0bXXXYYYYY to 0b00000XXX
    // v is a trusted signal
    type <-- v >> 5;

    // prepare constraint checking for `type`
    signal three_upper_bits;
    // 0b11100000 = 0xE0
    // v is trusted signal
    three_upper_bits <-- v & 0xE0; // 3 upper bits of v (0bXXX00000). v can only be 8 bits.

    // should_only_be_lower_bits is 0b000YYYYY
    // we get it by 0bXXXYYYYY - 0bXXX00000 to get 0b000YYYYY
    var should_only_be_lower_bits = v - three_upper_bits;
    // we're checking that should_only_be_lower_bits can only be LESS THAN 32 (0b00011111)
    // that verifies that three_upper_bits are pristine and were not messed with.
    // if someone were to mess with three_upper_bits, should_only_be_lower_bits would contain higher bits
    // and be more than 32 (0b00011111).
    // by doing that, we cryptographically assert that should_only_be_lower_bits is in the form of 0b000YYYYY
    signal upper_bit_1;
    signal upper_bit_2;
    signal upper_bit_3;
    upper_bit_1 <-- should_only_be_lower_bits & 0x80; // 0b10000000. This signal can be 0bX0000000
    upper_bit_2 <-- should_only_be_lower_bits & 0x40; // 0b01000000. This signal can be 0b0X000000
    upper_bit_3 <-- should_only_be_lower_bits & 0x20; // 0b00100000. This signal can be 0b00X00000
    upper_bit_1 === 0; // Assert that 0bX0000000 is 0b00000000
    upper_bit_2 === 0; // Assert that 0b0X000000 is 0b00000000
    upper_bit_3 === 0; // Assert that 0b00X00000 is 0b00000000

    // generate constraint for type signal
    // 2^5 = 32
    type * 32 === three_upper_bits;
}

component main = MAIN();
```

The comments go through my thinking, but essentially I verify the signal assignments with substraction/multiplication constraints.

Comment: You can combine the three `upper_bit_` bit checks if you use 0xE0

Comment: That's true. I also think I need to double check that v is only 8 bits and not more.

Comment: Also you may have just hidden the problem here: `three_upper_bits <-- v & 0xE0;` I'm not sure this really does safely verify.

Comment: @meshcollider that's a very good point! I have no clue what i'm doing. I'm still not sure what's the safe way to verify `>> 5` operation.

Answer (score 0):

`circomlib/circuits/sha256/shift.circom` has a `ShR` component which performs right shift.

```
    var InputBits = 8;
    var ResultBits = 3;

    // convert v to bits
    component n2b = Num2Bits(InputBits);
    n2b.in <== v;

    // shift
    component shr = ShR(InputBits, 5); // v >> 5
    for (var i = 0; i < InputBits; i++) {
        shr.in[i] <== n2b.out[i];
    }

    // convert back to number
    component b2n = Bits2Num(ResultBits);
    for (var i = 0; i < ResultBits; i++) {
        b2n.in[i] <== shr.out[i];
    }
    type <== b2n.out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution for the error.

//Code Begins

pragma circom 2.0.0;

template MAIN() {

```
signal input v;
signal output type;
signal rs;

rs <-- v >> 5;
type <== rs;
```

}

component main = MAIN();

//End of code

Regards